# How can I make this query work in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I have to following code:

```cs
private static bool DoesColValueExist<T>(IQueryable dataToSearchIn, string colName, string colValue)
{
    int noOfClients = 1;
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (colValue != "" && colName != "")
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(colName);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        Expression left = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
        left = Expression.Call(left, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(colValue.ToLower(), typeof(string));
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
        Expression searchExpression = Expression.Call(left, method, right);


        MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { type },
            dataToSearchIn.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(searchExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }));
        var searchedData = dataToSearchIn.Provider.CreateQuery(whereCallExpression);
        noOfClients = searchedData.Cast<T>().Count();

        if (noOfClients == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It works with LINQ to SQL but with LINQ to Entities, I get the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What are the types of the columns? Are they not strings? Why not convert the `colValue` to the appropriate type and do the comparison then? The operations L2E supports are limited by design.

Comment: Just skimming the question, I wonder if you might want to look at either DynamicQuery or PredicateBuilder in LINQKit - the former @ http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx and the latter @ http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Linq to Entities does not support .ToString() method. I also am not sure if this is a great idea to use string comparison for types that are not strings. But not all is lost. I came up with the following solution:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string X { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> Entities { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());

        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            if (!ctx.Entities.Any())
            {
                ctx.Entities.Add(new MyEntity() { ID = 1, Type = 2, X = "ABC" });
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(DoesColValueExist(ctx.Entities, e => e.X, "aBc"));
            Console.WriteLine(DoesColValueExist(ctx.Entities, e => e.X, "aBcD"));
            Console.WriteLine(DoesColValueExist(ctx.Entities, e => e.Type, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(DoesColValueExist(ctx.Entities, e => e.Type, 5));

        }
    }

    private static bool DoesColValueExist<TEntity, TProperty>(IQueryable<TEntity> dataToSearchIn, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> property, TProperty colValue)
    {

        var memberExpression = property.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null || !(memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Property expected", "property");
        }

        Expression left = property.Body;
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(colValue, typeof(TProperty));
        if (typeof(TProperty) == typeof(string))
        {
            MethodInfo toLower = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[0]);
            left = Expression.Call(left, toLower);
            right = Expression.Call(right, toLower);
        }

        Expression searchExpression = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Equal(left, right), new ParameterExpression[] { property.Parameters.Single() });

        return dataToSearchIn.Where(lambda).Any();                
    }
}
```

The nice thing about it is that it is more type safe than string based solution - the value of the parameter has to be the same as the value of the property. The property in turn has to be a member of the entity that is the generic type of the IQueryable'1 passed as the first parameter. Another helpful thing is that when coding against this method intellisense will show you member of the entity when you start typing the lambda expression for the second parameter. In the method itself I added an exception for string type when I call .ToLower() on both property value and the requested value to make the comparison case insensitive. For non-string types the values are compared "as is" i.e. without any modifications. 
The example above is complete - you can copy and paste it to a console app project (you need to reference EntityFramework.dll though).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static bool DoesColValueExist<T>(IQueryable dataToSearchIn, string colName, string colValue)
{
    int noOfClients = 1;
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (colValue != "" && colName != "")
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(colName);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        Expression left = property.PropertyType == typeof(string) ? propertyAccess : Expression.Call(propertyAccess, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
        left = Expression.Call(left, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(colValue.ToLower(), typeof(string));
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
        Expression searchExpression = Expression.Call(left, method, right);


        MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { type },
            dataToSearchIn.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(searchExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }));
        var searchedData = dataToSearchIn.Provider.CreateQuery(whereCallExpression);
        noOfClients = searchedData.Cast<T>().Count();

        if (noOfClients == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically, if the property is string then it doesn't call the `ToString()` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another option will be to always use the type of the property. If it's a string, then make both lower (the value to search and the property in the expression). If not, try to parse the string to the property type. If you can't parse it, then return false. If you can parse it, use that value in the expression ;)

Comment: This is what I did in the solution I proposed. Also calling .ToString() on non-string columns will not work - you will see the same exception saying that .ToString() is not supported.

Comment: But your solution is not dynamic, it's not the same

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In my solution I used typed information - so it does not take the column name as string but as a property on the entity of the IQueryable. This way you cannot specify a column name that does not exist. Also it does not take the value as string - it takes a value of the type of the property you are trying search against. So it is not dynamic in a sense you can specify anything since it prevents from specifying incorrect values. But it is dynamic as it allows to specify any property on the entity and use any value that is of the property type.

Comment: Yep, and the proposed API receives the name, not the lambda. I'm assuming that's by design and needed that way, that's the point of the whole question

Comment: But the name is used to get the property name on the entity using reflection - this is exactly what the lambda is for - with string it will fail at runtime if the colName does not match a property on the entity. With lambda you cannot specify incorrect name. Note that the lambda is bound to TEntity but it is explicit. With string you bind it implicitly to T with reflection at runtime.

Comment: I think I just got what you are saying. With string colName for the given entity type you can check different colmn values at runtime which is not possible with the lambda. That's true.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the column name is sent as a querystring parameter or something